# Desktop is empty after upgrading to 16.04, can't log in on tty

Tags: upgrade, login

I upgraded to **Ubuntu 16.04**. It turns on and I type the password. It's accepted and a "system problem detected" pop up appears when I open my computer. After I click cancel it closes but the screen is empty, only the desktop picture is shown.

I tried to open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> but nothing. I opened <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and when I want to login it says login incorrect (I typed my username and password correctly), and I can't do anything on my computer. What should I do? I don't want to lose my files.

Comment: The question is unclear. There is no "Ubuntu 16". It is unclear what did you upgrade to what and how. You can always boot from a Live USB and backup your files and then do a fresh install of a supported Ubuntu version. We can't guess what has happened to your system.

Comment: Uubunt 16.04.01. how can I back up my files if I can't access the terminal or throgh GUI ? ( I am new to ubuntu btw) during the upgrade, it said there was some error at upgrading some packages but I said to ignore it, and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Error messages are displayed for a reason. Do you know what they said? What does the "System problem detected" say besides that, any extra information?

Comment: As I said you can boot from a Live USB and access your files from there. @LoreHozan

Comment: It said that it couldn't upgrade 3 packeges, I can't remember which ones because they had very long names.There is no extra info, I can only click cancel or report problem which does nothing, I also have to click 3 times before it closes.( sorry if my english is bad)

Answer (score 1):

[Boot from live cd/usb](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#0), mount your disk, open it, navigate to `/home/myusernamehere` and copy your files to USB stick or somewhere else

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do that. I'm new to this stuff and I'm really afraid I might do something stupid again.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu? By booting to a USB or CD? If you do that again, there should have been a point where it asked you "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu". Click "Try Ubuntu" and it'll load up a temporary version from the live USB or CD. Then, plug in a USB with enough space for your files, copy your files to it, and your files are now safe. If worse comes to absolute worst, your files will at least be backed up.